# Distorted font in toolbars and any system windows

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-font-family

My fonts on toolbars and system (Ubuntu 14.04) windows look like this image: http://tinypic.com/r/21juc6o/8

I've tried changing the theme and font size but it's still very unreadable. This sometimes affects some letters in my terminal but mostly just folders and system settings.

Help?